# What benefit does using `in` have over object.prop?

Tags: javascript

We all see the feature detects doing something like:

```
var touch = function () {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window;
};
```

But I'm wondering if there are any other benefits to using the `in` operator over something like this (which saves a few bytes)?

```
var touch = function () {
  return !!window.ontouchstart;
};
```

Are there any other benefits to using `in`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both are entirely different.

When you do

```
!!window.ontouchstart
```

you are checking if the value of `window.ontouchstart` is [truthy](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values), but

```
'ontouchstart' in window
```

checks if `ontouchstart` exists in `window` object.

**Another problem** with using `!!window.ontouchstart` to check member existence is that, even if `ontouchstart` exists and if it has a falsy value, for example `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0`, it will still return `false`. So, it should NOT be used to check the member existence.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense!